# How to create a self-referential Python 3 Enum?

Tags: python, python-3.6

Can I create an enum class `RockPaperScissors` such that `ROCK.value == "rock"` and `ROCK.beats == SCISSORS`, where `ROCK` and `SCISSORS` are both constants in `RockPaperScissors`?

Comment: Why not a regular class with attribute value and beats?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Because an `Enum` nicely encodes the semantics of a collection of related constants rather than an arbitrary class. That said, would it be much simpler as a regular class?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Enum members are *instances* of the type. This means 
you can just use a regular property:

```
from enum import Enum

class RockPaperScissors(Enum):
    Rock = "rock"
    Paper = "paper"
    Scissors = "scissors"

    @property
    def beats(self):
        lookup = {
            RockPaperScissors.Rock: RockPaperScissors.Scissors,
            RockPaperScissors.Scissors: RockPaperScissors.Paper,
            RockPaperScissors.Paper: RockPaperScissors.Rock,
        }
        return lookup[self]
```

Answer (score 6):

By picking the order of the members carefully, each member can simply be described as beating the previous with a `property`.

```
from enum import Enum

class RPS(Enum):
    Rock = 0
    Paper = 1
    Scissor = 2

    @property
    def beats(self):
        return list(RPS)[self.value - 1]

for v in RPS:
    print(v.name, 'beats', v.beats.name)
```

### Output

```
Rock beats Scissor
Paper beats Rock
Scissor beats Paper
```

Answer (score 5):

Having `Enum` members refer to each other during class creation is a bit tricky; the trick is knowing that each member is created and initialized before it is added to the `Enum` itself.  This means you can examine the state of the `Enum` you are creating and make adjustments to both the member-being-created as well as members-already-created.

The basic problem here is making circular references between the members, and we can solve that by modifying the circle with each new member:

```
class RPS(Enum):

    Rock = "rock"
    Paper = "paper"
    Scissors = "scissors"

    def __init__(self, value):
        if len(self.__class__):
            # make links
            all = list(self.__class__)
            first, previous = all[0], all[-1]
            first.beats = self
            self.beats = previous
```

and in use:

```
>>> print(RPS.Rock.beats)
RPS.Scissors

>>> print(RPS.Paper.beats)
RPS.Rock

>>> print(RPS.Scissors.beats)
RPS.Paper
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Answer (score 3):

What about something like this:

```
from enum import IntEnum

class RPS(IntEnum):
    Rock = 1
    Paper = 2
    Scissor = 3

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self == RPS.Scissor and other == RPS.Rock:
            return True
        if self == RPS.Rock and other == RPS.Scissor:
            return False
        return self.value < other.value

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if self == RPS.Rock and other == RPS.Scissor:
            return True
        if self == RPS.Scissor and other == RPS.Rock:
            return False
        return self.value > other.value
```

It's not Rock.beats, but it seems more logical for who beats who to be on the enum (or the class), it's not an inherit property of Rock to beat Scissor, it's how we define RPS (could have just as well be the other way around if you decided to try something else)
And with the python method **ge** (and you can implement the rest if needed) you can get comparison naturally looking like this:

```
from itertools import combinations
members = list(RPS)
for pair in combinations(members, 2):
    print(f'{pair[1].name} < {pair[0].name} ? {pair[1] < pair[0]}')
    print(f'{pair[0].name} < {pair[1].name} ? {pair[0] < pair[1]}')

    print(f'{pair[1].name} > {pair[0].name} ? {pair[1] > pair[0]}')
    print(f'{pair[0].name} > {pair[1].name} ? {pair[0] > pair[1]}')
```

which outputs:

```
Paper < Rock ? False
Rock < Paper ? True
Paper > Rock ? True
Rock > Paper ? False
Scissor < Rock ? True
Rock < Scissor ? False
Scissor > Rock ? False
Rock > Scissor ? True
Scissor < Paper ? False
Paper < Scissor ? True
Scissor > Paper ? True
Paper > Scissor ? False
```

Comment: I like the idea of using `__ge__`, but Rock > Scissor should be true, right?

Comment: Thanks, fixed. Needed to use both __ gt__ and __ lt__ to have a complete ordering.

Comment: You should also add an instance check to make sure you're comparing apples with apples (returning `NotImplemented` otherwise)

Comment: What happens if both players choose Rock?

Comment: Your `Rock` and `Paper` members need to lose the comma in their definition as that makes their values be tuples instead of integers.

Comment: @EthanFurman, thanks for your comment, however in this case the comma doesn't indicate a single-tuple. It's true that the comma is redundant, and that it has no effect and can be removed.
Note that even with the comma: print(type(RPS.Rock.value)) will print <class 'int'> and print(RPS.Rock.value) will print 1. Also because the inherited type is IntEnum anything that isn't an int (or convertible to it using int() ) will cause a ValueError when the Enum is parsed.

Comment: Ah, right you are.  The comma does, in fact, create a single-item tuple, but then that tuple is passed to `int()` where it is correctly converted.  It is still a bad habit to have, though, as most other types of `Enum` will end up with a tuple as the value.

Comment: @EthanFurman, you are right that it's a bad habit, I will change the answer. However, `int((1,))` throws a TypeError, so something still doesn't sit right with your explanation.

Comment: The way the `value` is passed to a mixed-Enum is `obj = __new__(*value)` so a 1-item tuple becomes `obj = __new__(1)`.  Interestingly, you could say `ROCK = 'A', 16` which would become `obj = __new__(*('A', 16))` which becomes `__new__('A', 16)` which becomes `ROCK.value == 10`.  Thank you for making me get my story straight.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try?

```
from enum import IntEnum

class RPS(IntEnum):
    Rock = 1 
    Paper = 2 
    Scissor = 3

RPS.Rock.beats = RPS.Scissor
RPS.Paper.beats = RPS.Rock
RPS.Scissor.beats = RPS.Paper

for i in [RPS.Rock,RPS.Paper,RPS.Scissor]:
    print(i, "beats", i.beats)
```

Output:

```
RPS.Rock beats RPS.Scissor
RPS.Paper beats RPS.Rock
RPS.Scissor beats RPS.Paper
```

Yes. You can.

---

In python all (*) things are objects and you can attach further properties onto them:

```
def func():
    pass

func.result = 42

print(func.result)  # 42
```

---

*) few exceptions apply

Comment: Can I declare the `beats` property *within* the class, or do I have to do it outside?

Comment: @l0b0 I guess one could try to do something with decorators - not sure and no time to fiddle right now - maybe look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/7505395)

Comment: I prefer this since it declares the relationship early rather than late.

Comment: Googling "flansh" doesn't seem to bring up any pertinent explanation. Apparently this is a German slang word?

Comment: @trip who would have thought. It might be german - I was under the impression it has something to do attatching somthing to some other thing:  [here (german)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flansch) - in english it would be [flange](https://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/to+flange+sth.html). Reworded answer.

Comment: One issue with this approach is that the instance dict just remains writeable- any other code can put RPS.Rock.beats = "potato".  If you using property/descriptors then you get a read-only attribute.

Comment: @wim I would prefer yours over mine

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake, it could be done like this as well. It's more descriptive, but requires this `getattr` call, which I'm not the biggest fan of, personally.

```
from enum import Enum

class RockPaperScissors(Enum):

    ROCK = ("rock", "scissors")
    PAPER = ("paper", "rock")
    SCISSORS = ("scissors", "paper")

    def __init__(self, value, beats):
        self._value_ = value
        self._beats = beats

    @property
    def beats(self):
        return getattr(RockPaperScissors, self._beats.upper())
```