# python methods in comparison

Tags: methods, enums, pytorch

Rock, Paper, Scissors variable bot has default value
Variable Alex, has values that are passed to main.py
When I call method comparison I get an error
Method comparisons
from secrets import choice
from variants import Variants

**Player.py**

```
class Player:
    name = '',
    choice = ''

    def __init__(self, choise = 'ROCK', name = 'bot'):
        self.name = name
        self.choice = choice
    
    def whoWins(self, bot, alex):
        if bot.choice > alex.choice:
            print('bot, winner')
        if bot.choice < alex.choice:
            print('Alex, winner')
        if bot.choice == alex.choice:
            print('draw')
```

**main.py**

```
from variants import Variants
from player import Player

bot = Player()
alex = Player(Variants.ROCK, "Alex")
print(bot.whoWins(bot, alex))
```

**variants.py**

```
from enum import Enum

class Variants(Enum):
    ROCK = 1,
    PAPER = 2,
    SCISSORS = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `Variants` is the trailing comma after `ROCK` and `PAPER` -- the comma turns the value into a `tuple`, so

- `ROCK.value == (1, )`
- `PAPER.value == (2, )`
- `SCISSORS.value == 3`

Comment: it seems to me that the problem is not there, the problem is in the WhoWins method, the methods cannot be compared, but I'm scratching my head how to designate them so that the program knows exactly who won

Comment: `if bot.choice > alex.choice:  
 TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'method'`

Comment: @9RoxXx: It may not be the whole problem, but it's definitely a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:
I had to modify the comparison of methods, I did it like this:
also main.po remained the same:

```
> from variants import Variants from player import Player
> 
> bot = Player() alex = Player(Variants.ROCK, "Alex")
> print(bot.whoWins(bot, alex))
```

variants.py remained the same

```
from enum import Enum

class Variants(Enum):
    ROCK = 1
    PAPER = 2
    SCISSORS = 3
```

**Player.py**

```
from secrets import choice
from variants import Variants

class Player:
    name = '',
    choice = ''

    def __init__(self, choice = Variants.ROCK,  name = 'bot'):
        self.name = name
        self.choice = choice
    
    def whoWins(self, bot, alex):
        if (bot.choice == Variants.ROCK and alex.choice == Variants.PAPER):
            print('Alex, win!')
        if (bot.choice == Variants.PAPER and alex.choice == Variants.ROCK):
            print('Alex, win!')
        if (bot.choice == Variants.SCISSORS and alex.choice == Variants.SCISSORS):
            print('draw')
        if (bot.choice == Variants.ROCK and alex.choice == Variants.ROCK):
            print('draw!')
        if (bot.choice == Variants.ROCK and alex.choice == Variants.SCISSORS):
            print('Bot, win')
        if (bot.choice == Variants.SCISSORS and alex.choice == Variants.PAPER):
            print('Bot, win')
        if (bot.choice == Variants.SCISSORS and alex.choice == Variants.ROCK):
            print('Alex, win!')
        if (bot.choice == Variants.PAPER and alex.choice == Variants.SCISSORS):
            print('Alex, win!')
        elif (bot.choice == Variants.SCISSORS and alex.choice == Variants.SCISSORS):
            print('draw!')
```

**if bot.choice > alex.choice:    TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'method' - The error is gone**

**All, is ok!**

```
PS C:\Users\user\2> python.exe main.py
Alex, win!
PS PS C:\Users\user\2>
```

Comment: Cool.  You can also check this [rock, paper, scissors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57085357/208880) solution.